# Issue with SVN Commit for certain File Extension

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having problem with uploading file to SVN repository from Tortoise SVN. I can upload all files except some specific files which always fail

List of Files

Rhino.Mocks.dll
System.Data.SQLite.dll

Microsoft.Ajax.debug.js

On SVN the error log contained  these entries.

```
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:33 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Unable to PUT new contents for /Futures/!svn/wrk/31a3597a-ac95-9a4f-a234-bedc059f9c32/MyFolder/trunk/ExternalLibraries/RhinoMocks.dll.  [403, #0]
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:33 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Could not prepare to write the file  [500, #160044]
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:33 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Cannot write to the prototype revision file of transaction '11-n' because a previous representation is currently being written by this process  [500, #160044]
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:41 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Unable to PUT new contents for /Futures/!svn/wrk/544b013d-1d26-ab4b-9ecf-4aab76f7bee3/MyFolder/trunk/ExternalLibraries/System.Data.SQLite.dll.  [403, #0]
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:41 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Could not prepare to write the file  [500, #160044]
[Tue Dec 15 15:03:41 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Cannot write to the prototype revision file of transaction '11-o' because a previous representation is currently being written by this process  [500, #160044]
```

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you,
The Mar

**Edit: Results:**

Turning off AniVirus didnt help in my case.

I restarted Apache - Same results

I copied the dlls  listed above and did a committ- it worked. It seems the cause of the issue might have been corrupted dll, but then when did it get corrupted? The project was able to use these dlls without any exceptions. I opened the javascript file adding an extra space in the header and saved it back. I was able to commit the file.

For now the issue is solved but still not sure what was the cause.

I am new to SVN - should I have done something else to the files other than Add before commiting?

Answer (score 4):

my guess: an antivirus

Comment: yep, could be antivirus or some sort of firewall or port's blocked on the server that svn is hosted on.

Comment: Assuming we are using svn+http, if it was an antivirus or firewall, you wouldn't probably expect an HTTP status code back. You would expect your request to be dropped. If you are getting an HTTP status code back (which we are in this case) then presumably the requests are making it to the server but something is screwing up from there, so it doesn't seem like a firewall/antivirus issue.

Comment: @ashchristopher @ Dave,
 I would like to believe that it should have something to do with AntiVirus as McAfee Enterprise has always been an issue with some of our ports. I disabled McAfee antiVirus but same error message in SVN Tortoise and SVN logs on server.

Comment: Did you mean an antivirus on the client or the server?

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem was asked about before:

[Unable to commit to Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339170/unable-to-commit-to-subversion)

It's not exact (your server is complaining that the *same* process can't write to the file, instead of another process).

To summarize: Try restarting the server.  Failing that, there might be a stuck transaction.  Failing that, **just somebody**'s hunch is a good one.

Comment: @ZoogieZork
Thank you for the link. Not sure how I missed when I searched SO.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 and 500 status codes are a good place to start. Looks like there is a problem with your svn server.

403 = Forbidden   (permissions issue?)

500 = Internal Error   (something is f'd)

Comment: @ashchristopher
I did check for permissions and in frustration I did give full permissions,but I got the issue solved in unexpected way. please see edit

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "global ignore pattern" that could be causing the problem?  Check your Tortoise general settings.  I believe it ignores DLL files by default, not sure about the others.

Comment: @josh I have checked the Global Ignore patters (and I have added some myself ) they do not contain these extensions. To make it clear Jquery scrip files gets uploaded and it was only asp.net ajax javascrip files

Answer (score 0):

You said you turned off your antivirus and it didn't help.
But are you absolutely sure that the antivirus didn't interfere even though you turned it off?

Because I've seen it with several antivirus products now that they try to prevent the user from doing (what they consider) stupid things and just *pretend* to be turned off but still interfere and 'protect' the user.

Depending on the antivirus product you have, you might have to uninstall it, reboot and then try to commit your files again. If this doesn't help, you're free to install your antivirus again if you like.

Comment: @stefan- Uninstalling is not an option for me. I will though work with my network admin during next week (when everyone else is gone :-)) to uninstall the software  and see if it helps. I will update here itself what was the outcome. Thank you